# How to get C# (analyzer) suggestions visible on the commandline?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, dotnet-cli, roslynator

What I like about the `dotnet` CLI is that you can run `$ dotnet build --no-incremental`, and you always get a list of all the warnings in your project. I use that for making sweeping changes, and such, on projects. Output of that can be piped to unix tools, for further processing.

I'd like to also get that for the 'suggestions' that you get in Visual Studio. Is that possible, and how?

## Suggestions?

What I mean by suggestions are the "messages" you get in the "Error List..." in Visual Studio (see below). The compiler calls this "Information that does not indicate a problem" ([`DiagnosticSeverity.Info`](https://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Diagnostic/DiagnosticSeverity.cs,22)), EditorConfig calls these suggestions ([`EditorConfigSeverityStrings.Suggestion`](https://sourceroslyn.io/#CodeStyleConfigFileGenerator/DiagnosticSeverityExtensions.cs,37)).
[image]

## How to reproduce?

A minimal reproduction for this, is to create a new console application, and add a new class with a private field, **but don't make it `readonly`** (see below)! This will trigger `IDE044` (as in the screenshot), but it won't show up when running `$ dotnet build --no-incremental`. If you override the severity via the `.editorconfig` file, then the suggestion does show up, but obviously as warning.

### Class1:

```cs
public class Class1
{
    private string Foo = "bar";
}
```

### `.editorconfig`

```
[*.cs]

# IDE0044: Add readonly modifier
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0044.severity = warning
```

## Sidebar: What am I looking for?

I'm looking for something "out of the box", so something like `$ dotnet build ...`. However, if that's not possible, I'd be fine to use a 3rd party global tool, like the [Roslynator Command-Line Interface](https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator#roslynator-command-line-interface) (I did try that path, but didn't manage to get that to work).

I'm well aware that you *could* write a custom tool, on top of the Roslyn API, but I think that's quite brittle, as you need to cater for all the intricacies of package restore, finding MSBuild, and so on. I think this is really something that should be available out of the box, or otherwise deserves an issues on a project upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know it that works out to you, but you can use the [`ErrorLog` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#errorlog) on the project to output all diagnostics to a [SARIF](https://github.com/microsoft/sarif-tutorials/blob/main/docs/1-Introduction.md) file.

Comment: Awesome! It's a bit convoluted, as you don't get the output on the std output, so it requires a bit of shell magic. Though, it better than nothing, and definitely helps. Thnx!!

Comment: SARIF is not supposed to be directly consumed by humans. The intent is to have it processed by tools.

Comment: I understand. I've tested a bit with this, but the analyzer violations don't show up in the SARIF file, because of that, I'm not accepting this answer so far.

Comment: If you're looking for `IDE????` diagnostics, you need to add the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle) to have the compiler do that instead of Visual Studio.

Comment: No, not necessarily, just any kind of "message" that shows up in Visual Studio. However, your comment did uncover why my reproduction stopped working. I was first working with an analyzer I added explicitly (analyzer package from xUnit), but for my reproduction scenario, I wanted to have minimalistic example, and switched to an `IDE????`  violation.

When I do this with a violation of xUnit, then it does work :tada: This way, I also learned about the CodeStyle package. Thank you!

Comment: I just found out that the package is not even needed. The CodeStyle analyzers are disabled by default indeed, but there is a MSBuild property to enable them: [`EnforceCodeStyleInBuild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enforcecodestyleinbuild) ;)